# Pig - System cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, apache-pig

I have error in pig latin while i run the basic command "Dump Students" for the file

`>Students = LOAD 'C:\\Users\\avtar\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\student.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray,age:int, phone:chararray, city:chararray);`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obq9Q.png)

Comment: The actual error says it can't find the file specified. For example,  do you really have a Desktop folder inside OneDrive?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the help sir, I copied the path of that file from its properties and yes i do have desktop folder in onedrive folder .

Comment: Maybe pig cannot read from OneDrive since it's a mounted filesystem, not really on your local machine. Have you tried using other files outside that folder?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sir my file is loading properly i guess because in my friends laptop its the same but after i write " Dump Students" then i get some errors but in my friends laptop required output is achieved:  I am getting 2 warnings of same and 1 error . The warning says > NativeIO.chmod error (2): The system cannot find the file specified and the error says  ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias Students.

Comment: It cannot open the iterator because it cannot find the file... In don't know what else to tell you